# How to make the CSS external link (target="_blank") icon accessible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, accessibility

I want to automate the attribution of an "external link" icon to links which go off-site (ie where the `a`-tag includes `target='_blank'`). I have so far been successful in this using pure CSS by doing this:

```
a[target="_blank"]:after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.8em;
    content: " \e164";
}
```

This works. However, the drawback here is that it does not satisfy the accessibility rules since someone relying on a screen reader does not see the icon. The solution would be to modify the title attribute of the `a`-tag to say "Opens in new window" (or better still perhaps to add this to the existing title attribute). I do not think there is any way of doing this in CSS so I was trying to use jQuery which I know a little bit but don't use on a regular basis.

I tried this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $($("a").attr("target","_blank")).attr("title", "My external link");
});
</script>
```

But it changes all the `a`-tags and not just the ones with `target='_blank'`. I must be getting something wrong in the jQuery select - but I can't see what (and I have tried looking at the jQuery docs and even tried the `.each()`-function, without success).

Help on this, or even alternative suggestions for how to achieve the desired effect, would be welcome.

Comment: `$('a[target="_blank"]').attr("title", "My external link");`

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a[target='_blank']").attr("title", "My external link");
```

You forgot your selector :) You're better off adding a class to all the a-tags you want, otherwise you can iterate through them using `.each()`

```
$("a[target='_blank']").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("title", "My eternal link");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So, as per the other answer and my comment, you are selecting all `a` tags in your jquery and should use `$('a[target="_blank"]').attr("title", "My external link");`

However, some screen readers will not see this update and still read the original title text. (remember you are adding this after page render)

If you are adding target _blank to the `a` tag you should also add the new title (if possible). you might be adding no benefit if the screen readers don't see you updated title text